# Crystal Report Shows blank Page on Windows server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I have crystal report files that i push data to from dataset and then transmit the report to pdf or word or excel depending on user selection. I don't show it with crystal report viewer at all.
Just yesterday, on one windows server 2012 web server, it started showing blank pages for every report after updating the web application. Nothing has changed on the server.
I use crystal report 2008_x86, sap says the 2008 version should not work on server 2012 but it has always been the one on it and it has been working till yesterday.
When i connect to the server with my dev machine it shows, but on the server itself, it is not.
Please any help will be good since it's mission critical.
An example of how the data is sent is here

```
<pre><code>
private void BindRpt()
    {
        eReports obj = new eReports();
        DataSet oData = obj.rptClassTeacher(TeacherID, TermID, YearID);
        rd = new ReportDocument();
        string path = "School/ClassTeacher.rpt";
        reportPath(rd, path);
        rd.SetDataSource(oData);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        userPreference(rd);
    }

private void userPreference(ReportDocument rd)
    {
        rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Report");
    }
```

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the crystal runtime on the server? perhaps something got messed up with the runtime. i would try just to be sure. also, doublecheck your web.config to make sure the latest app deploy to the server didn't override it? Is the only thing that changed on the server is deploying a new version of your app?

Comment: Have done re-installation a couple of times with still the same result. The web config file has not changed, but i restored it from backup to also confirm. Still the same issue, have tried updating crystal report with new current versions, nothing seems to work.

Comment: @douglast, I just recognized that, exporting to pdf is the problem, if i should export to Microsoft word, the report comes with the data and all intact, try export to pdf and then blank.   rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, Response, true, "Report");  <br/> works, any suggestion as to why the pdf export is no longer working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the culprit to this, taken a long time but thought i will put the answer that worked for me here to in case someone faces this same issue.

I uninstalled Windows Update KB3102429. And behold, it's working again.
You can read about it [here](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2016/01/kb3102429-re-issued-still-breaking-things/). Though Adam Fowler talks about how it affects Outlook, it solved the blank page in crystal report export.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After auto install framework 4.6 in Windows Server 2012, IIS begin to link the crystall report to `./aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_1069` and from VS2010 (W7/FW 4.0) publish to link `./aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319`.
For that it's in blank, I only create the 4_6 dir with the files in 4_0 into server and it is working.
In the future, when I update VB and link to 4_6, I must also update the correct 4_6 version the server.

Comment: in the aspnet_client/system_web/ under the inetpub, the only other folder i have is 2_0_507.. There is no 4_6_1069 or 4_0_30319, or i should check somewhere else?